# Автозакрытие PR на GitHub

Tags: php, git, github

Не знаю как подойти к этому вопросу.
Попробую рассказать все как есть.

У меня много Open source проектов на GitHub. Для их тестирования и анализа я пользуюсь такими проектами как:

- Scrutinizer
- SensioLabsInsight
- Coveralls
- StyleCI
- TravisCI

С недавних пор обратил внимание что если я запускаю анализ кода на StyleCI и создаю PR с правками оформления кода, то PR, после сборки, автоматом закрывается и ветка удаляется. Закрывается PR естественно от моего имени, что не очень приятно. Приходится восстанавливать ветку, переоткрывать PR и мерджить его в мастер.
Пример такого [PR](https://github.com/anime-db/anime-db/pull/167).

Небольшие исследования показали что сборка PR завалилась из-за [покрытия кода](https://coveralls.io/builds/9811668).

```
Coverage decreased (-0.03%)
```

Погуглив немного я наткнулся на следующий [тикет](https://github.com/lemurheavy/coveralls-public/issues/790) в репозитории Сoveralls.
Разработчики SonataAdminBundle столкнулись с аналогичной проблемой.

Получается проблема явно у сервиса Сoveralls, но мне не понятно другое. Почему PR закрылся? У SonataAdminBundle аналогичный [PR](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/3894) не закрылся. Да, ошибка есть. Но с PR ничего автоматически не делалось.

Возможно это как-то связано с названием PR:

```
Apply fixes from StyleCI
```

Из-за слова `fixes` GitHub мог пытаться что-то сделать автоматом. Если ошибок не было то все [ОК](https://github.com/peter-gribanov/geoip-api-php/pull/2), но это не объясняет почему PR закрылся.

Небольшое гугление показало что это не частая проблема, но есть аналогичные примеры [1](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog/pull/112), [2](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-failed-job-monitor/pull/29).

Может у кого есть идеи куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

может сюда копать:

- https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages/
- https://help.github.com/articles/closing-a-pull-request/  (пункт 4)

похоже, что:

- Coveralls в любом случае удаляет ветку (хоть fail, хоть OK)
- а github автоматом удаляет PR для не существующей ветки

Comment: не, если все ОК, то ветка не удаляется. В [этом](https://github.com/peter-gribanov/geoip-api-php/pull/2) примере автоматом ничего не происходило. Я сам смерджил PR и сам удалил ветку